# Limiting background-color to width of more dimensional heading

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a background color (#fff) to stick strictly to the text of the more line headings and not the entire width of the container. I understand that block level elements take up the entire width of the page, so I was wondering if there was a way around this besides forcing only to apply my background to the text.

i have a heading more line heading like this with a img background like this.

Banana 
Camtipon Grant 
Award 
Announcement 
2020

i tried it with span but i rly failed, im new to this.

EDIT: Here is the picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/hm2AS.jpg

Comment: some images would help us understand what youre asking to do

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert `<span>` with text inside header.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body style="background-color: blue;">
    <h1 style="background-color: #fff">Header with wide background</h1>
    <h1><span style="background-color: #fff">Header with text background</span></h1>
</body>
</html>
```